# How can I add RecyclerView row to the WishList

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I need to Implement WishList like a google play in my app .In the each row of my

`RecyclerView` in the `QuestionActivity` , I have a one Button (Heart Icon). I

want when this heart icon clicked ,This row of `RecyclerView` Add to wishlist Activity .

I know that , I should save this entry with `onClickListener` of Heart button in

the database and show entries with `SELECT`  In the wish list activity , But my

RecyclerView Populate with Json Data and Image and it have a download link

(download with android download manager)

> know my question :

what is the best practice for this work ?

1.save the json data in the database and showing that

or ... (do you have a suggestion)?

`

Comment: please construct question more accurate. For now it looks strange

Comment: as you can see in the google play . with clicking on the add to wishlist .it add the recycler item to wish list . my question is what is the best approach for doing this work (not on the static data like a info on the database). i need rhe best approach for json data

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options, the option to put the data in the database when the `onClickListener` for that specific item is called seems like the best option to me. Altho, don't forget to notify the `Adapter` the clicked item has to be redrawn by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `notifyItemChanged(position)`.

You can also add a callback listener to your `RecyclerView`'s `Adapter` which can return the clicked item to the `Activity`, but this will only make things more complicated and there is no need to do this.

Comment: thanks . did you mean that . when user click on the button i should save the json data in the database ?

Comment: Yea you could do that, depends on the way you communicatie with your database, if you need to make an instance of your db first, maybe the callbacklistener to the activity is a better option